# Как вычислить бесконечную сумму с заданной точностью?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, ряды

[image: Бесконечная сумма]

Помогите написать программу, вычисляющую бесконечную сумму с заданной точностью.
Как этот пример/условие преобразовать в формулу?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Прочитайте, [как правильно задавать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), попробуйте для начала написать что-то сами и приведите пример вашего кода.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Для знакопеременного монотонно убывающего сходящегося ряда отличие частичной суммы от бесконечной по модулю не больше последнего члена.

Так что просто суммировать, сравнивая абсолютное значение последнего члена с заданной погрешностью.

На всякий случай - сумма вашего ряда равна (1/e-1), где e, понятно, 2.71828....

Comment: @pavel, а можешь на какую-то теорему сослаться? Насколько я помню, там два индеска брались везде, а не какой-то член.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4#%D0%9E%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86935/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-------).